# get exit code always returns 1

Tags: c, windows, exit-code

I am working on a project that includes threads and processes. I open multithreads and for each thread I open a proess that runs an exe file.
In case that a program is finished with a returned value that is not 0 it is crashed, and the returned value is supposed to be printed. in order to get the returned value I use the WIN API function GetExitCodeProcess()
my problem is that this function always return the value 1, even when the program supposed to be crashed, but why?
here is my relevent code:

```
static DWORD WINAPI RunningTests(test_s *test)
{
    PROCESS_INFORMATION procinfo;
    DWORD waitcode;
    DWORD exitcode;
    int status = 0, crashed = 0;
    char cmdLineString[MAX_NUMBER_OF_CHARS_IN_CMD_LINE]="";
    char *cmdLineStringPtr = cmdLineString;

    (test)->isCrashed = 0;
    CreateCmdLine((*test).testExePath, &cmdLineStringPtr);
    status = CreateProcessSimple(_T(cmdLineString), &procinfo);
    if (status == -1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    waitcode = WaitForSingleObject(procinfo.hProcess, 
    TIME_UNTIL_TIMED_OUT_IN_MILLISEC);
    if (waitcode == WAIT_TIMEOUT) /* Process is still alive */
    {
        strcpy((*test).status, "Timed Out");
        CloseHandle(procinfo.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(procinfo.hThread);
        return 0;
    }
   crashed = GetExitCodeProcess(procinfo.hProcess, &exitcode);
   if (crashed == 0)  /* Process is crashed */
   {
        strcpy((*test).status, "Crashed");
        (*test).isCrashed = 1;
        (*test).returnedCrashedValue = exitcode;
        CloseHandle(procinfo.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(procinfo.hThread);
        return 0;
    }
    CloseHandle(procinfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(procinfo.hThread);
    return CompareFiles(&test);              
}
```

Comment: From MSDN: _If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero. If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError._

Comment: how `GetExitCodeProcess` success or failure related to process crash ?!  if you passed to api valid process handle with `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION` or `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` access - the `GetExitCodeProcess` will return true. because `procinfo.hProcess` always valid and have required access - the `GetExitCodeProcess` and must always return true

Comment: and look for `exitcode` exit sense only if `GetExitCodeProcess` return true. but you do opposite - look it on failure, what is wrong. and you close handles from 3 places, instead of single

Answer (score 1):

You should be looking at exitcode, not crashed;

> Return Value
>
> If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero.
>
> If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error
>   information, call GetLastError.